Basic books and documents to read for a comprehensive guide to US law
What are good books, docs, or PDFs for US and Virginia Law? There is the Constitution and Bill of Rights, but are more modern documents available?

When I was about 15 I found a book in the school library titled The Law, and checked it out. I found out the difference between criminal and civil cases, the difference between torts and breaches of contract, the fact that some laws are called statutes and others are called ordinances, the fact that lawyers in some contexts call all persons under the age of majority "infants", and a lot of other basic stuff like that. I don't remember the author's name. But something like that, if it can be found, might serve your purpose.

@MichaelHardy Thanks man!

There is no such thing as a basic book or document that can provide a comprehensive guide to U.S. law.
American law is a sprawling patchwork of laws enacted at the federal, state, local, and tribal levels. It includes laws as enacted by legislatures, as promulgagted by executive agencies, and interpreted by judiciaries over two and a half centuries. It regulates virtually every facet of life, from the colors you may paint your house, to traffic regulation, to environmental protection, to basic human rights, to the president's authority to preemptively launch a nuclear war.
If there are specific areas of the law that you are intersted in, a more focused question would likely yield better results.

Okay is their any good sources you have in this regard?

@Haridasa You need to be very specific. For example, if you're concerned with driving, the manuals used in driver education school would be be a good guideline to the most important rules of the road.

@Barmar I am interested in laws regarding comas

Post a new question with the specific type of information you're looking for. And explain the context -- is this from the perspective of a medical professional, family member of the coma victim, etc.? Are you looking for information about terminating life support?

But don't get your hopes up. This is a pretty arcane area of law, there's not likely to be much information available to lay people. If you really need to know, you should contact a lawyer.
